# Django raw query - connection.cursor() data is not showed

Tags: django

When I use Table.objects.raw(raw query), I can see data. When I use connection.cursor(), cursor.execute(same raw query), data is not showed in a HTML page. What's the cause?

oracle    11g
cx-Oracle 7.2.2
Django    1.11.22

```
#ORM raw query - It's OK.
class UserList(ListView):
    query = 'select user_id, user_name from user'
    queryset = USER.objects.raw(query)
    context_object_name = 'user_list'
    template_name = 'user_list.html'

# Problem - data is not showed in screen.
class UserList(ListView):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('select user_id, user_name from user')
        queryset = cursor.fetchall()
        context_object_name = 'user_list'
        template_name = 'user_list.html'

#user_list.html
<h2>User List(ListView Sample)</h2>
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>        
        <th scope="col">User ID</th>
        <th scope="col">User Name</th>
    </tr>
    {% for user in user_list %}
    <tr>
        <th width="200"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/sec/userlist/{{ user.id }}/">{{ user.user_id }}</a></th>
        <th width="200">{{ user.user_name }}</th>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

No error messages. But data is not showed in a HTML page

Comment: Well by using `.fetchall(..)` you do *not* interpret the results as `User` objects (in this case). But using raw queries is actually not a good idea in the first place (so is using hardcoded URLs, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons here:

1. A `QuerySet`, even a `raw(..)` one, is *not* executed eagerly: it is done lazily. So that means that the query will run when you render the page. Django's `ListView`, will copy the queryset each time, and thus make the query each time you fetch the objects; and
2. By using `Model.objects.raw(..)` the result of the query is *parsed* into `Model` objects. By performing a `.fetchall()`, you retrieve a list of *tuples*, not a list of model objects.

Using raw queries in general is however not a good idea (both using cursors, and `Model.objects.raw(..)`. A model is not a table. A model is a Python object, with a lot of extra logic to wrap/unwrap values, and defines extra objects. The Django ORM will furthermore protect you against small changes you make in your models (like renaming a column at the database side, etc.). Furthermore given the ORM is implemented correctly, it will not generate queries that have incorrect syntax, etc.

Therefore it is advisable to use the ORM, and thus write it as:

```
class UserList(ListView):
    query = 'select user_id, user_name from user'
    queryset = USER.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'user_list'
    template_name = 'user_list.html'
```

> **Note**: The name of Django models is usually written in `CamelCase`, so `User` instead of <s>`User`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually, I want to know how to use raw query in Django program. If I have to use complex select query that many tables are joined (more than 3 tables),   How do I develop a django program? Use raw query or Use ORM?

Comment: @Terry: usually using raw queries is the last resort, and using cursors is not a good idea at all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I need to use complex queries like 'START WITH CONNECT BY'. How can I implement the query in a Django program?

Comment: @Terry: usually that is done through modeling the data in a better way, so for example by using `django-mptt`, `django-treebeard`, `django-tree`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comment is very helpful to me.